# Change a color of a text line when clicked with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new into JavaScript and I've been trying to change the color of a text line in my website when I click on it with JS, I know there are ways to do it just with CSS but I'd like to practice some JS, this is what I've been trying so far:

I have this list:

```js
function white() {
  const input = document.getElementById("weekly");
  input.style.color = "white";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="weekly" href="/index.html" onclick="white()">Weekly</a></li>
</ul>
```

*It is a longer list but i didn't want this to look messy :)*

I want to change the color of "Weekly" when it's clicked on and this is what i have tried:
I've been trying for a while and this is the best I came up with but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is working as far as I see: https://jsfiddle.net/wso8qert/ (I didnt change your code at all). Can you explain your behavior?

Comment: I pasted your code in a snippet and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally `<a>` tags redirect you to a link but you can avoid redirection and then apply custom function to `<a>` tag by using `preventDafault` function which will stop default behaviour of an element

```js
function white(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const input = document.getElementById("weekly");
  input.style.color = "white";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="weekly" href="/index.html" onclick="white(event,this)">Weekly</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although only for a split second, the anchor tag's text is indeed styled to be rendered as white text. Your anchor tag takes the user to `/index.html` and thus the effect is not visible for as long as the user is on the page. To avoid redirecting, set the `href` attribute to `#`:

```js
  function white() {
    const input = document.getElementById("weekly");
    input.style.color = "white";
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="weekly" href="#" onclick="white()">Weekly</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *"set the href attribute to `#`"* - or just remove it altogether, to prevent scrolling to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your very same code snippet works. The issue you are facing is that your `<a>` tag has a link, that is navigating to what I assume the same page, hence the page is reloaded and the link is black again. See withoud the `href` (and a more visible color):

```js
function white() {
  const input = document.getElementById("weekly");
  input.style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="weekly" onclick="white()">Weekly</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works fine, but might make it a little more generic so you can use it in other ways, as example below.

```js
// es6 "fat arrow" one liner
changeColor = (element, color) => element.style.color = color;

// maybe more familiar
// function changeColor(element, color) {
//  element.style.color = color;
// }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="weekly" href="#" onclick="changeColor(this, 'red')">Weekly</a></li>
  <li><a id="daily" href="#" onclick="changeColor(this, 'blue')">Daily</a></li>
  <li><a id="hourly" href="#" onclick="changeColor(this, 'green')">Hourly</a></li>
</ul>
```